# System.ListException: Duplicate id in list. But how come?

Tags: trigger, list, set

I am getting an error: System.ListException: Duplicate id in list. In my Trigger. But I really don't see a reason this should happen. Here is my code:

```
Set<Order__c> ordersToUpdate = new Set<Order__c>();
//...
if(!ordersToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
   List <Order__c> ordersToUpdateList = new List<Order__c>();
   ordersToUpdateList.addAll(ordersToUpdate);
   update ordersToUpdateList; // This is the line getting the error
}
```

As I understand, elements in set will never be duplicate. So the list coming from the addAll of a set shouldn't be. Any reason why this is not the way?

Comment: This should not happen , but can you put a debug and see if its happening just before you update?

Comment: this is nicely covered here: http://foobarforce.com/2013/09/10/sobject-secret-life-equality-sets-maps/

Answer (score 2):

Ive encountered this error as well and it stumped me for second too. You are correct, Sets can not contain duplicates. The important distinction is that the **entire Order record has to be a duplicate**, not just the ID.

The error you are getting is only for a Duplicate ID. The means there is two or more records in your Set with the same ID, and some other field on the Order is different to make them not a *complete* duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

I guess I understand the reason. Seems to be a bug of Salesforce to me.

Explained in the below experimental code:

```
Set <Order__c> orderSet = new Set<Order__c>();
List <Order__c> originalList = [Select id, name From Order__c ];
orderSet.add(originalList[0]);
orderSet.add(originalList[1]);
originalList[0].name = 'test';
orderSet.add(originalList[0]);
System.debug(orderSet);

List<Order__c> orderList1 = new List<Order__c>();
for(Order__c o : orderSet) {
    orderList1.add(o);
}
```

The size of orderSet is 2, consisting of two elements which is correct. But the size of orderList1 is 3, containing two elements with name 'test'.

Comment: This is not a bug .Every time you do .add it adds to list .To update you need to get that element and make change .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava, but did you notice that there are two of them having the name 'test'? And did you notice there are only two objects in the set?